# Uploading inputs field and images to database and pictures folder

Tags: php, reference

[it was submitted successfully but I still have any error saying undefined index pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JEfsB.jpg) [is is he code please someone should help me out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAzrS.jpg)

I expect there should be no error code and the file is should also save in pictures folder

Comment: This is not even a question. Take the tour on [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).